# Spotfire - Line from Column Value won't render in Log x-axis

Tags: spotfire

I have a set of data I want to plot using a line chart, and a secondary column of data that is the calculated limits of the data.

When I use 'Line from Column Data' in the Lines and Curves property, the limits column line will display fine as long as my x-axis is in linear scale.

When I want to swap to log scale (this is audio data) the limits column line is no longer visible. The data does not need to be updated for log since my y-axis is unchanged and the x-axis for the test data and the limits data is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue.  I was able to get the line to plot though if I made a calculated column taking the log of the line plotting through the 'Line from Column Data', e.g. Log10([Column]) and use that column in the 'Line from Column Data'.

You can include two lines generated from the 'Line from Column Data', one for the linear y-axis with the original column and one for the log y-axis with the log10 calculated column and then you'll have the line you need regardless of which y-axis you use.

Comment: The issue is I don't need a log converted y-axis. I only want the x-axis converted. If I were to convert they-axis the data would be non-useful.

Comment: My apologies, I misread you initial question.  I cannot get a line to plot they way you have described.  I'm able to log the x-axis and then use that as the x-axis for the 'Line from Column Data' but of course that doesn't provide the correct answer.  I've even tried raising 10 to the power of each value on the x-axis and then take the log of that as the x-axis for the plotting but that doesn't seem to work either.  Seems like this may be a bug with the program.  Have you contacted Tibco?